# regex match entire word ( characters between whitespace ) that contain letters in this order

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to match an entire words, characters between whitespace, if it contains the letters PRP in that case and in that order in javascript.

What I'm trying to do is select all words that contain PRP and replace them with a ( space ).

Here is a regex that I could come up with that matches anything with the letters p or r or p: `\b(?=\w*[PRP])\w+\b`.

once I know the regex my plan is to do str.replace(matchAllWordsWithregex, ' ');

So what is the regex and how do I say all words with this regex in the replace function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the square brackets around `PRP` if you want the literal text `PRP` to match (because with them, you're creating a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) that matches either a `P` or an `R`):

```
\b(?=\w*PRP)\w+\b
```

But you don't actually need a lookahead assertion (nor word boundaries) here:

```
\w*PRP\w*
```

will work just fine (for alphanumeric "words"). To replace all matches in a string `subject`, you can use

```
result = subject.replace(/\w*PRP\w*/g, " ");
```

If you define a word as "anything except whitespace", use

```
result = subject.replace(/\S*PRP\S*/g, " ");
```

Comment: Thank you, but when I test it, it is just replacing the PRP not the entire word.

Comment: I want to replace the entire word that contains PRP

Comment: I'm looking to match all the characters in between whitespace that contain PRP whether they are letters or symbols. White-space is the delemitre.

Comment: Then you need to use `\S` instead of `\w` because the latter only matches alphanumerics (and underscores).

Comment: Thank you. How can I get it to also match symbols in the word?

Comment: in how are you(PRP) `/\b\S*PRP\S*\b/g` matches all of you(PRP , but not the last parentheses. How do I get it to match the last parentheses?

Comment: I removed /w . weren't those the word boundaries?

Comment: nevermind. sorry i was being stupid. I figured it out.